# How to get the Number Phase Uncertainty relation from the Energy time relation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I can arrive at $\Delta H\Delta t \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$, but how do I get from there to $\Delta N\Delta \phi \geq 1$ for the number states of light?

I know we write $H = \hbar \omega (N + \frac{1}{2})$, but then won't there be an $\omega$ term in the relation? And I have no idea of how to get from time to phase.

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221a/coherentstate.pdf